# forkJoin but next observable depends on the one before

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, observable, fork-join

https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin

```
const example = forkJoin({
  // emit 'Hello' immediately
  sourceOne: of('Hello'),
  // emit 'World' after 1 second
  sourceTwo: of('World').pipe(delay(1000)),
  // throw error
  sourceThree: throwError('This will error')
}).pipe(catchError(error => of(error)));

// output: 'This will Error'
const subscribe = example.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

That's the main implementation but in my case, to call `sourceTwo` I need to use the data from `sourceOne` and the same with `sourceThree`. All calls need the previous observable in order to fetch data.

I only care about final result, don't need to merge anything, just do what this example does, show what `sourceThree` returns

Comment: That means you should be piping to `sourceTwo` and `sourceThree` instead of creating one with forkJoin, you cannot run them in parallel.

Comment: thanks @pascalpuetz but it doesn't

Comment: can you provide an answer with the code to accept it @JuanMendes?

Comment: The linked answer is only one of a multitude of questions like yours. Another example would be this one here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69421293/how-to-chain-requests-correctly-with-rxjs/69424143?noredirect=1#comment122710203_69424143
Not sure why there's a need for another question that asks basically exactly the same.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[forkJoin is intended to run calls in parallel](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin#why-use-forkjoin), like `Promise.all()`. In your case, you cannot do that since the calls depend on each other.

Instead, [you can pipe them](https://rxjs.dev/guide/operators#piping). If you can parallelize 2 and 3, you can do something like the following.

```
sourceOne.pipe(
  res => forkJoin(makeCall2(res), makeCall3(res))
)
```

To complete the Promise comparison:

```
makeCall().then(res => Promise.all([
    makeCall2(res),
    makeCall3(res)
]));
```